# Why is np.linalg.norm(x,2) slower than solving it directly?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, norm

Example code:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import time

x=np.ones((2000,2000))

start = time.time()
print(np.linalg.norm(x, 2))
end = time.time()
print("time 1: " + str(end - start))

start = time.time()
print(math.sqrt(np.sum(x*x)))
end = time.time()
print("time 2: " + str(end - start))
```

The output (on my machine) is:

```
1999.999999999991
time 1: 3.216777801513672
2000.0
time 2: 0.015042781829833984
```

It shows that np.linalg.norm() takes more than 3s to solve it, while the direct solution takes just 0.01s. Why is np.linalg.norm() so slow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.linalg.norm(x, 2)` computes the 2-norm, taking the largest singular value

`math.sqrt(np.sum(x*x))` computes the frobenius norm

These operations are different, so it should be no surprise that they take different amounts of time. [*What is the difference between the Frobenius norm and the 2-norm of a matrix?*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33083/what-is-the-difference-between-the-frobenius-norm-and-the-2-norm-of-a-matrix) on math.SO may be of interest.

Comment: Slightly off-topic and merely out of curiosity, do you happen to know how one computes the operator norm for p!=2?

Answer (score 0):

What is comparable is :

```
In [10]: %timeit sum(x*x,axis=1)**.5
36.4 ms ± 6.11 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [11]: %timeit norm(x,axis=1)
32.3 ms ± 3.94 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Neither `np.linalg.norm(x, 2)` nor `sum(x*x)**.5` are the same thing.